# How to transfer folder from Amazon Web Services to ASP.NET Server remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

I have a folder on Amazon Web services and I want to transfer it to ASP.NET Server.

The Folder has huge size and I have a limited internet capacity so I can't download it and re-upload it via ASP.NET Web Forms.

so is it possible ? and How could I do it ? or What I should search for this ?

P.S: as I searched all I found was the other way around and I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: You mean the folder is on Amazon S3? You can explore the .net SDK of aws s3 to interact with s3 and download file and folder from there.

Comment: I don't want to download due to the internet capacity, I want to transfer it directly to the server.

Comment: Where is your server located?

Comment: my server is on smarterasp.net

Comment: If your server is outside of aws then you can not access the file of s3 without internet.

Comment: I didn't mean without internet, I meant without downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a service that do the exact thing I want via FTP.

As the user registers two FTPs and he can copy/migraine the files/folders you want from one to the other.

[Multcloud: Manage, migrate, transfer, copy, and move files between any cloud storage services.](https://www.multcloud.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have folder on EC2 you can do scp [unix command to copy files from Linux to linux]

if you have it on S3; you can expose it as public folder; and then on Azure you can download it using wget/curl